# Find first recurring character using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Input: array=[2,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,4]
>
> Output return 2
>
> Input: array=[2,1,1,2,3,5,1,2,4]
>
> Output return 1
>
> Input array=[2,3,4,5]
>
> Output return undefined

I run my code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DistinctConcreteMatch) and it always return undefined.

Is there any improve ways to let undefined disappear?

Also how to return undefined in third input?

What i try in my JS:

```js
   
function FirstRecurringCharacter(arr){
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== i) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    break;
  }
}
};
   
 FirstRecurringCharacter([2,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,4])//should return 2
   
 FirstRecurringCharacter([2,1,1,2,3,5,1,2,4])//should return 1
   
 FirstRecurringCharacter([2,3,4,5])//should rerturn undefined
```

Comment: When you want to return something, you should use a `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
function find(array) {
    var s = new Set;
    return array.find(v => s.has(v) || !s.add(v));
}

console.log(find([2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4])); // 2
console.log(find([2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4])); // 1
console.log(find([2, 3, 4, 5]));                // undefined
```

Comment: OK..What are .add and .has mean?

Comment: If set already has the element then add else return ans because now you got same element again

Comment: `add` is to add a value to the set and `has` test the set, if the value is in the set.

Comment: why the !s.add instead of just s.add? trying to wrap my brain around that...

Comment: @ToddAustin `s.add(v)` is to add the value to the set. this returns always the instance of the used set. the second expression is now always truthy, but not wanted, because only the first part should decide and if a value is not in the set, it should return a falsy value.

Answer (score 3):

You should return the value, not log to console.

```js
   
function FirstRecurringCharacter(arr){
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== i) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};
   
 console.log(FirstRecurringCharacter([2,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,4]))//should return 2
   
 console.log(FirstRecurringCharacter([2,1,1,2,3,5,1,2,4]))//should return 1
   
 console.log(FirstRecurringCharacter([2,3,4,5]))//should rerturn undefined
```

Comment: I only modified your code, @Nina Scholz's answer is better, you should refer to it.

Comment: Ari Can you please explain why there is no `arr.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1` in the condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstReccuringChar(arr) {
  let map = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (map[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
      return arr[i];
    } else {
      map[arr[i]] = i;
    }
    console.log(map);
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(firstReccuringChar([2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]));
```

// Another example using Hash Tables or Objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Your answer will be more helpful if you described the code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstRecurringCharacter(input) {
  let result = {};
  let len = input.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (result[input[i]] !== undefined) {
      return input[i];
    } else {
      result[input[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the problem. As stated, in the exact same answer above. This is obviously a question in a classroom or online course regarding hash tables. It should have been obvious by the posters question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You said it's the exact same answer as another answer. Which one, and why post a new answer if they're the same? It would help for you to include some explanation as to how this solves the problem in ways that haven't been posted already

Comment: needed answer with explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstReccuringChar = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
          if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
            return arr[i];
         }
        }
     }
  return undefined;
  };
```

**this is another solution but it's not the best one because it's O(n^2)**

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to log to console and also seems like you are attempting a naive solution, I presented my solution in the same manner.  Time Complexity is O(n^2).

```js
function firstRecurringCharacter(input) {
  let index = Infinity;
  let firstRecurringValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
      if (input[i] === input[j]) {
        // Edge Case: Selects lowest index repeated while traversing through the nested loop
        if (j < index) {
          index = j;
          firstRecurringValue = input[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return firstRecurringValue !== 0
    ? console.log(firstRecurringValue)
    : console.log(undefined);
}
firstRecurringCharacter([2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]); // returns 2
firstRecurringCharacter([2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]); // returns 1
firstRecurringCharacter([2, 3, 4, 5]); // returns undefined
```